# Gif takes too long to load in uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif

I can very easily load images into my UITableView asynchronously, but when I try loading a gif, I run into a crap ton of problems.

1) If I scroll down the table and back up, the gif disappears and takes like 5 seconds to come back. This doesn't happen with normal images
2) The gif wont animate. It's just the first frame of the gif.

I'm using this library to load the gif:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ImageLoader {

var cache = NSCache()

class var sharedLoader : ImageLoader {
  struct Static {
    static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in
        var data: NSData? = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData

        if let goodData = data {
            var image = UIImage(data: goodData)

            if (urlString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("gif") != nil) {
                image = UIImage.animatedImageWithData(goodData)
                println("gif")

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            })
            return
        }

        var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                return
            }

            if data != nil {
                var image = UIImage(data: data)
                if (urlString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("gif") != nil) {
                    image = UIImage.animatedImageWithData(data)
                                        println("gif2")

                }

                self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: urlString)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                })
                return
            }

        })
        downloadTask.resume()
    })

  }
}
```

and then I'm trying to display the image in cellforrowatindexpath:

```
 ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("thumbnail") as NSString, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in

     cell.thumbnail.image = image
     cell.thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw

})
```

Comment: I suggest looking into this if you're going to display gifs on iOS: https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: You should animate an array of uiimages instead of a gif.

Comment: how would I college the images into an array?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` doesn't support animated GIFs out of the box. In order to show animated GIFs in your app you'll want to use something like [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) or [OLImageView](https://github.com/ondalabs/OLImageView).

Comment: It also looks like you're not doing any caching of images. Animated GIFs can be very large, so you'll likely want to cache them on disk using something [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).